# How do I carve up this data in to compose an email in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

To cut a long story short, I have an array of data which is sent via Ajax to my php script.

The array is made up of an unlimited amount/type of form inputs. I retrieve the input ID and value and push them to said array.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];

foreach($data as $d) {
  echo $d;
}
```

Using the code above I am able to console.log the response as

```
&name=John Doe&email=johndoe@example.com&message=Message Content
```

How can I carve up this string to use as separate variables in PHP.. for example `$name` or `$email`?

Comment: looks like you are making it hard on yourself when you send the ajax. Show the basics of ajax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not submit each data as a seperate $_POST entry in the first place? Using javascript you can serialize the form inputs as you have shown and submit the following serialized data:

```
&name=John Doe&email=johndoe@example.com&message=Message Content
```

This can be done using the jQuery script:

```
var formdata = $("#formid").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./urltoajaxpage.php",
    data: formdata,
    success: function(data){
        // success
    },
    error: function(data){
        // fail
    }
});
```

Then when you submit that information to your PHP page you could retrieve it as:

```
$_POST["name"]     // John Doe
$_POST["email"]    // johndoe@example.com
$_POST["message"]  // Message Content
```

Comment: I suspect that OP uses `serialize()` function on form before sending it using `ajax`.

Comment: I explained the full process. Yes, it appeared as though OP was already serializing the form data.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. No, I wan't using serialise - I'm fairly new and didn't know it existed.